# React Native - make image size not change when keyboard is open?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I have a few images in a React Native project that are scaling whenever the keyboard is open. What is the best property to give them to maintain their size despite the keyboard being there?

current image styling example:

```
  background: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
  logo: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '40%',
    bottom: '5%',
  },
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of code that you can share that can demonstrates this issue?

Comment: edit: updated with example

Answer (score 4):

You are using percentage based sizes, and I'm going to guess that you are testing this on Android, as the default is to resize the view when the onscreen keyboard is open (It adds `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to the main `Activity` in `AndroidManifest.xml` [See this line of code in github.com/facebook/react-native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1e8f3b11027fe0a7514b4fc97d0798d3c64bc895/local-cli/templates/HelloWorld/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L23) )

To avoid this resize issue, you have two options -

- Change `adjustResize` to `adjustPan` in the AndroidManifest.xml
- Don't use percentage based sizes for the logo. Or if it's an Image, just set the width and allow the height to be set based on the image size.